# about special operation in python

Tags: python

I'm reading the tutorial in pytorch website, and I get confused about the following code:

```
masks = mask == obj_ids[:, None, None]
```

note that mask is a matrix, [[0, 0, 0],[1,0,0],[1,2,1]] for example

while obj_ids is a list [1,2] e.g.

the result returns 2 * matix_shape matrix

I think this operation is cool and  I wonder how this happens

Comment: l,ooks like numpy indexing, pytorch has tensors: https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/notes/tensor_indexing.html maybe look into that direction.,   also maybe tag pytorch. Not sure this is a valid question though....

Comment: @Reti43: Thanks a lot. None operation can be regarded as the unsqueeze operation in some way. Haha!